# iis asp.net core 6 cannot load index.html

Tags: asp.net-core

I have just upgraded to Asp.net Core 6.0 . **Everything works fine** except for one thing;
When I try to access the application either from IIS or a browser:

Ex http://localhost/CondoQA2/  I get following msg: This localhost page can’t be found 404

If I do the following from a browser or I browser from IIS
http://localhost/CondoQA2/Index.html I have access to the application and all the various api calls from controllers work fine.
Both web.config and Index.html reside in the root folder of CondoQA2. This happens both on the QA server and the production server.
Here is the code in program.cs:

```
    var app = builder.Build(); 
    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
    app.UseResponseCaching();
    app.UseResponseCompression();

    DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
      options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
      options.DefaultFileNames.Add("Index.html");
    app.UseDefaultFiles(options);

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.MapControllers();
```

// Following was tried and this code did not fix the problem
// I do not have any controller with Action of Index????

```
    app.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "default",
      pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    app.MapFallbackToFile("ClientApp//dist");

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
      spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp//dist";
    });
    app.Run();
```

This problem seems to be a code 18 (ie 18 inches from the keyboard)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to test the sample code from the first snippet and it works on my side. It launches the index.html which is stored in the wwwroot folder. If you run the application from Visual Studio, which URL do you see in the browser? does that open the index.html page? What is CondoQA2 in your app? Is it a separate folder or it is your app name? On my side URL looks like https://localhost:44391/ which is different than yours.

Answer (score 2):

I recreated the application in IIS and now it works.

Comment: so delete this question pls